# No puedo ver imágenes de gallery en dispositivo

Tags: ionic3

Realizo una app en Ionic 3.20, en particular una galería de imágenes. Con ionic serve las veo perfecto, salvo que algún momento tuve error 403 (se solucionó  solo, una vez que las abrí vía navegador en forma independiente, comenzaron a verse normal, sin el 403).

Luego cuando genero la apk y corro la app en el dispositivo, las imágenes no se ven, solo el ícono.

```
var url = 'www.vvvvvvvvvvvvv.com.ar/php/cargogallery.php';
this.http.get(url)
//.map(res => res) // linea comentada
.subscribe(data =>
{
  this.images = data["records"];
```

---

```
<ion-grid *ngIf="images">
<ion-row>
  <ion-col *ngFor="let photo of images" [attr.col-6]="grid ? true : null" [attr.col-12]="!grid ? true : null">
    <div>
      <img src="{{photo.URLImagen}}" #myImage (click)="presentImage(photo.URLImagen,photo.NombreIdioma)">
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

[image: pantall en el móvil]

Comment: Aclaración: Cuando hago click sobre la imagen (bah..., sobre el icono) y voy a verla en pantalla con el viewer, se ve perfecta en el dispositivo.

Comment: Las imágenes tienen como nombre 001.jpg...002.jpg...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto! un problema al parecer bastante común. Hice una copia de seguridad del archivo .htaccess y luego lo borré de la carpeta public_html. reinicié todo y anduvo perfecto. Muchas gracias